# how to Ignore All errors from $channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss

Tags: magento, zend-framework

I am currently pulling in information from an external Review Site and displaying those reviews in the sidebar of my website using $channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss('http://externalurl.com/feed')

However if the external website is for some reason down (like it was this weekend) this bring all my pages with this embed down with the default Magento error handling - "There has been an error processing your request, Error log record number: XXXXXXXXXXX"

Is there any way I can stop this from hapening?

Thanks in advance - James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is sending an exception than you can handle it with **try catch**

```
try {
  //Your code

}
catch(Exception $e) {
  //Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I could, that tick was a little hidden.